# For $1$, $2$, and $n$ dimensions we have "line", "plane", and "hyperplane". What's the term for $3$ dimensions?

Tags: geometry, terminology, plane-geometry

If in $1$-dimension we call it "line"; in $2$-dimension we call it "plane"; in $n$-dimension we call it "hyperplane".

My question is, what do we call it in 3-dimension?

Comment: I think hyperplane just refers to all dimensions above 2. There is no specific name made for the 3-dimensional hyperplane nor for any other dimension as it is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A space of dimension $0$ is called point, of dimension $1$ line, of dimension $2$ plane and then just space for $dim\ge 3$.

Hyperplane generally refers to a subspace of dimension $n-1$ inside a space of dimension $n$ thus:

In dimension $1$ the line is the whole space and point is hyperplane.

In dimension $2$ the plane is the whole space and line is hyperplane.

So the hyperplane in dimension $3$ would be just called (plain) plane.

In dim $4$ hyperplane of dim $3$ does not have a special name (except in Minkowski space, where it is called space but this is just because the last dimension is of different nature, i.e. time, but this is very special circumstance).